# Deleting tcl list returned from Tcl_NewListObj

Tags: c++, tcl

I created a tcl list using this function `Tcl_NewListObj` , if I don't have use for this tcl list, how do I do clean up? Should I call delete on `listPtr` in the code below?

```
    Tcl_Obj* listPtr = Tcl_NewListObj(0,NULL); 
    
    // some code where we decide we don't want to use listPtr
    delete listPtr; // delete listPtr is OK?
```

Comment: Only call `delete` if *you* called `new`. In fact, call neither, and use automatic allocation, containers, or smart pointers. But if you must deallocate something, do so with the corresponding deallocation function to whatever allocating function you originally called. That is: `free()` for `malloc()`, `delete` for `new`, `delete[]` for `new[]`, `SomeLibraryDealloc()` for `SomeLibraryAlloc()`, etc. Anyone providing an allocation function should document how you as a user are meant to deallocate the resulting object later; if they don't, you should file a bug with them. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Tcl_IncrRefCount()` and `Tcl_DecrRefCount()` to manage the reference count for the object; it will be disposed of correctly when the reference count is decreased to a value less than 1. (It *starts at zero;* an immediate `Tcl_DecrRefCount()` would destroy the list. The actual deletion function is `TclFreeObj()`, but *never* call that directly. `Tcl_DecrRefCount()` will call it when appropriate.)

***Do not `delete` the object!*** That won't work.

Tcl uses per-thread memory arenas for many things, and in particular for the `Tcl_Obj` structure (which has other optimisations as well), which hugely accelerates the system but does mean that you have to allocate and deallocate via Tcl's API.

---

In short, do this:

```
Tcl_Obj* listPtr = Tcl_NewListObj(0,NULL); 

// some code where we decide we don't want to use listPtr
Tcl_DecrRefCount(listPtr);
```

Note that if you decide to return the list as a Tcl result instead of disposing it, you can just do this:

```
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, listPtr);
```

without needing to manually manage the reference count. That's why reference counts start at zero. (Using an initial reference count of 1 was tried, but was found to offer no advantage while greatly increasing the amount of code bureaucracy.)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to clean up a (reference to a) Tcl_Obj that is no longer needed is via `Tcl_DecrRefCount`. In your case:

```
Tcl_DecrRefCount(listPtr);
```

Using `delete` is likely to leak memory in the best case scenario. When used on a shared value, it may even lead to a segfault of your program at some later stage.